# Use SendKeys in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I am trying to build a macro which automates few tasks; however, I am stuck in a step where an Add-In is triggered by using Keyboard shortcut `(Alt+Y1)`.

I tried passing the below snippet but doe not help much. Any help please?

```
Application.SendKeys ("%(Y1)")
```

Comment: Help us to help you, **post your current code.**

Comment: Application.SendKeys ("%(Y1)")

Comment: Have you tried without the inner parentheses? like ("%y1")

Comment: I seem to be missing my `Y1` key. Is that a regional variation of F1? Is it supposed to by `Alt-Y` followed by a `1`?

Comment: It is supposed to be 'ALT' followed by 'Y1'

Comment: In that case, @DanielSouza's advice should work